# System.Net.WebException not intercepted on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, restsharp

I am trying to call a web service using RestSharp (this has to be done for WP8 onwards).

This is my triggered method:

```
 private async void postRest()
 {
     string getSyncService = "MyService"; 
     var client = new RestClient(ip);
     var request = new RestRequest(getSyncService, Method.POST);              
     request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
     JsonObject jsonGenericRequest = new JsonObject();
     jsonGenericRequest.Add("companyid", "123");
     jsonGenericRequest.Add("token", "123");            ...
     request.AddParameter("GenMobileRequest", jsonGenericRequest);
     request.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
     request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
     request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

     try
     {
         // easy async support
         client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
         {
             Console.WriteLine("response content: " + response.Content);
             if (response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Completed)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("errorMsg: " + response.ErrorMessage);
             }
         });
     }
     catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(" "  + ex.InnerException.ToString());
     }
 }
```

On my log I am getting this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.ni.dll  and wasn't handled before a managed/native
>   boundary

I cant even keep any information in my handler

```
// Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" ---Application_UnhandledException---");
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

How can I get more info about what is wrong?

Any additional information on the proper way to call a WS would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a try/catch inside your lambda?

Comment: yes I did, as in the code, but without intercepting anything ...

Comment: No, there is no exception handling inside the lambda. You only have it around the call to ExecuteAsync.

Comment: This link has responded nicely to your question and explained it. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ptorr/2014/12/10/async-exceptions-in-c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is that exceptions from an Async Void Method Can’t Be Caught with Catch.

> Async void methods have different error-handling semantics. When an
>   exception is thrown out of an async Task or async Task method, that
>   exception is captured and placed on the Task object. With async void
>   methods, there is no Task object, so any exceptions thrown out of an
>   async void method will be raised directly on the
>   SynchronizationContext that was active when the async void method
>   started

The error is that the async void method needs to be changed to an async Task method instead.

Source is on msdn [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3824f24a-de3d-4ce7-a70d-d3055091f84f/systemnetwebexception-not-intercepted-on-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: That is only half the story. There is nothing wrong with `async void` methods **if** exceptions are handled inside the method itself. On the other hand, converting a method to return a `Task<T>` won't help unless someone is `await`ing it (or explicitly getting the `Result`) on the other end - inside a `try`/`catch` of course.

Comment: @PeterTorr, could you please provide an example of this second case?

Comment: Sure, added something [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2014/12/10/async-amp-exceptions-in-c.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ptorr/2014/12/10/async-exceptions-in-c/

```
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
  using System.Threading;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace AsyncAndExceptions
  {
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, e) => Log("*** Crash! ***", "UnhandledException");
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s, e) => Log("*** Crash! ***", "UnobservedTaskException");

    RunTests();

    // Let async tasks complete...
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    GC.Collect(3, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
  }

  private static async Task RunTests()
  {
    try
    {
      // crash
      // _1_VoidNoWait();

      // crash 
      // _2_AsyncVoidAwait();

      // OK
      // _3_AsyncVoidAwaitWithTry();

      // crash - no await
      // _4_TaskNoWait();

      // crash - no await
      // _5_TaskAwait();

      // OK
      // await _4_TaskNoWait();

      // OK
      // await _5_TaskAwait();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Log("Exception handled OK"); }

    // crash - no try
    // await _4_TaskNoWait();

    // crash - no try
    // await _5_TaskAwait();
  }

  // Unsafe
  static void _1_VoidNoWait()
  {
    ThrowAsync();
  }

  // Unsafe
  static async void _2_AsyncVoidAwait()
  {
    await ThrowAsync();
  }

  // Safe
  static async void _3_AsyncVoidAwaitWithTry()
  {
    try { await ThrowAsync(); }
    catch (Exception ex) { Log("Exception handled OK"); }
  }

  // Safe only if caller uses await (or Result) inside a try
  static Task _4_TaskNoWait()
  {
    return ThrowAsync();
  }

  // Safe only if caller uses await (or Result) inside a try
  static async Task _5_TaskAwait()
  {
    await ThrowAsync();
  }

  // Helper that sets an exception asnychronously
  static Task ThrowAsync()
  {
    TaskCompletionSource tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => tcs.SetException(new Exception("ThrowAsync")));
    return tcs.Task;
  }
  internal static void Log(string message, [CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", caller, message);
  }
}
```

}